# jQuery POST/AJAX not showing up in IE, works in FF

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, post

I've done my homework and scoured SO to no avail. I've even gone from $.post to $.ajax in an effort to clean out everything. There's no cacheing either.

```
$('#send').click(function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: "submit.php?ts="+new Date().getMilliseconds(),
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: $("#myform").serialize(), 
        success: function(data){
                $('#myspan').html(data);
        }
        });
   });
```

The form looks like:

```
<span name="loading" id="loading"></span>
<div id="myspan"></div>
<form onsubmit="return false;" method="post" action="#" name="myform" id="myform">
```

etc...

What am I doing wrong? This works marvelously in Firefox but nothing happens in IE.
The really weird part is that an `alert(data)` will show the right content in the alert box in IE. The "myspan" div doesn't have any styling or CSS to it either.

Comment: Does IE throw any kind of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the

```
<span name="loading" id="loading"></span>
<div id="myspan"></div>
```

were placed within a `<table>` tag.

Stupid IE.

grr.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are expecting a plain string as response: `dataType: 'text'`. Are you sure that this is what you are returning and that you also send the appropriate header (`content-type: 'text/plain'`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a submit button `#send` inside the form?

How about trying

```
var form=$('form#myform').submit(function(){
  //ajax, update html
  return false;
});
$('#send').click(function(){
  form.submit();
  return false;
});
```